# Heavy processing causing site to become unavailable

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cron

Once a month we have to generate and send out 10 thousand PDF bills. This is done by a cron job. It takes around 2.5 hours to complete, but the issue it that during this time the site is down. Is there any way to run the cron job and still be able to keep the site up? We don't have the resources to do this on a dedicated server.

We have one 16 core dedicated php server, 1 dedicated mysql server. we are calling a program we wrote in c++ from within php to make each pdf and sending it from php as a email.

I've tried adding `sleep` between generations, and this did not seem to help.

> How is the cron process? Do you like start now and generate and send 10000 for next 2.5 hours continually?

No, the cron is set to stop after 2.5 hours. We'll re-run it again the next night till it's all sent out. mostly its not needed

Comment: Use `sleep($delay)` between generations, where $delay is subject to experimentation. Try 1 to start with, and increase it. Clarifications (best edited into your question please): what do you use for the actual generation? How long does a single bill take to generate? Are you on a shared web host?

Comment: i have tried that and it didn't help

Comment: How is the cron process? Do you like start now and generate and send 10000 for next 2.5 hours continually?

Comment: Split the cron job in smaller pieces so I doesn't send 10000 bills in one request but e.g. in 1000 runs each time 10 bills

Comment: @Reeno that sounds like a possible solution. Will run some tests.

Comment: What is the actual bottleneck (it's probably the database), when the site is unavailable _what_ is the error (i.e. details from log files please do not say "HTTP 500 Internal server error" or similar). Have you tried simply setting a lower process priority with nice? I.e. make the cron job wait for resources not the web (will have no real effect if you're basically hammering the db).

Answer (score 2):

You should first determine what is the bottleneck of your process ( why the website is down ? ): database or CPU or network?

- If it is database, you should create a view are replicate your database and run your pdf batch creation on this database. You can also use indexes on db to boost your pdf creation.
- If it is CPU, you can try to add cache system to your website ( file cache or use memcach ).
- If it is network, you can check the ulimit on unix system which allows a max file size opened.